# Разное отображение шрифта на сайте в разных ОС

Tags: windows, вёрстка, шрифты

Случилась следующая беда делаю сайт, подключил сторонний шрифт с GoogleWebFonts. Шрифт ubuntu.

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu&subset=latin,cyrillic-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Какие бы варианты я не выбирал в настройках шрифта, остается одна проблема, отображение символов "к" и "й" в браузерах в Windows (проверил в WinXp и Win8 на GoogleChrome, FireFox и Opera) 
Прилагаю картинки для большей ясности:

[image]

Собственно вопрос, можно ли эту беду как то вылечить, уже готов сменить шрифт.

Comment: Обычно когда символ отсутствует в шрифте, он заменяется дефолтным из того же семейства.
Попробуйте сменить шрифт и отпишитесь о результате

Comment: В общем проблема в том что на разных экранах и при разных разрешениях, шрифт выглядит немного по разному, в WinXP было достаточно сделать приближение и всё нормально встало =) для четкости добавил в CSS "text-rendering" правда поддерживают его только на Gecko 1.9+ и WebKIT но для меня это не главное =)

P.S.: IE10 справился на отлично =)